# Reproducing OLS prediction Python statsmodel

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, predict

I've trained a OLS model in Python using statsmodels OLS.
With the code below i've trained the model:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X2 = sm.add_constant(lin_x_train)
est = sm.OLS(lin_y_train, X2)
est2 = est.fit()
```

Using est2.params I obtain the following paramters:

```
const       -0.394654
pow2         0.920915
eth_36hr    -0.028754
eth_24dhr   -0.068346
eth_16hr     0.064768
eth_72hr     0.001774
eth_48hr     0.001239
eth_24hr     0.026940
eth_2hr     -0.163568
eth_3hr     -0.042497
eth_4hr      0.033180
eth_5hr     -0.029850
eth_6hr     -0.040417
```

Now I want to predict the following case:

```
pow2         0
eth_36hr    2.91
eth_24dhr   1.34
eth_16hr    1.13
eth_72hr    13
eth_48hr    6.66
eth_24hr    -9.89
eth_2hr     -3.7
eth_3hr     2.37
eth_4hr     2.36
eth_5hr     -2.28
eth_6hr     -5.27
```

Since I've trained a OLS model I was under the assumption that it was simply:

```
y = a + B1 * X1 + B2 *X2 + .... Bn*Xn
```

When I compute this myself I get a Y value of 0.132
However using:

```
Xnew = newcase
Xnew = sm.add_constant(Xnew)
est2.predict(Xnew)
```

I get a value of 0.699

What am I missing?

N.b. using LinearRegression from sklearn I get the same value of 0.699. So I'm clearly missing something. But I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing was indeed quite simple and embarrassing.
I switched 2 variable names around, resulting in wrong predictions manually.
So, the formula was correct:

```
y = a + B1 * X1 + B2 *X2 + .... Bn*Xn
```

Before discovering it, I just worked around by saving the model and importing it to perform the predictions.